# Redirection Issues with Jekyll website on custom domain

Tags: wordpress, github, jekyll

I wanted to shift my blog to Jekyll from WordPress. I made a Github page with my website on it and added my blog's name to CNAME file in it's root. It redirects the Github page to my WordPress blog. On redirecting from WordPress to the Github page is basically refreshing my blog as it redirects to Github which in turn redirects to my blog only. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the CNAME or IP on your DNS to point to GitHub.

See the "Setting up DNS" section of this page: https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages